# Convert string variable to date

Tags: excel, date-format, vba

I need to convert a string variable to a date variable in a VBA macro, to process the date to get the mMonth and year in order to name the worksheet

```
Call GetMonthandYear(MonthYear, FileDate)
    ActiveSheet.Name = MonthYear
```

I looking to create a method called GetMonthandYear. FileDate is a String in a date format, `dd.MM.yyyy HH-mm-ss`. If I can change the variable to a date, I can change the format to `MMMM/yyyy` and then use `ToString`, I think, and assign it to `MonthYear`.

Is there a way to change the string to a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your proposed aaproach:

1. Converting strings to date serial can be problematic, with uncertanty if Excel will interpret the date as `dd.MM` or `MM.dd`.  Since you know the format in advance, extract the month and year directly.
2. `\` is not a valid character for sheet names.  I've used `_`, substitute as you wish

---

```
Function GetMonthandYear(FileDate As String) As String
    Dim dot1 As Long, dot2 As Long
    Dim m As String, y As String

    dot1 = InStr(FileDate, ".")
    dot2 = InStr(dot1 + 1, FileDate, ".")
    m = Mid$(FileDate, dot1 + 1, dot2 - dot1 - 1)
    y = Mid$(FileDate, dot2 + 1, InStr(FileDate, " ") - dot2 - 1)

    GetMonthandYear = Format$(DateSerial(y, m, 1), "MMMM_yyyy")
End Function
```

Call it like this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FileDate As String
    FileDate = "15.04.2012 16-31-18"

    ActiveSheet.Name = GetMonthandYear(FileDate)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CDate and Format functions?

Comment: Never heard of CDate but have just found ToDateTime method currently experimenting

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date using CDate function but it requires `-` to be replaced by `:` and `.` to be replaced by `/`.

```
Dim yourStringDate, sBuf As String
Dim yourDateVariable As Date

yourStringDate = "15.04.2012 16-31-18"
sBuf = Replace$(yourStringDate,"-", ":")
sBuf = Replace$(sBuf, ".", "/")
yourDateVariable = CDate(sBuf)

MsgBox yourDateVariable
```

Comment: It seems your method should work but I keep geting a type mismatch `Sub GetMonthandYear(MonthYear, FileDate)
    Dim dateBuf As Date
    dateBuf = CDate(Replace$(FileDate, "-", ":"))
    
End Sub`