# mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss how can I extract date?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I extract only the date in excel-vba from this format mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss?

I need to compair two dates in this format but I only want to know if the day is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string variable to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162424/convert-string-variable-to-date)

Comment: hi see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486863/string-to-date-accessing-date-only-from-now-function/19487460#19487460) which will let you get date part and then compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if cell A1 = 04/16/2013 10:28:12

then put that in cell B2

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

or concatenate components if you need a different order ie.

for `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
=MONTH(A1) & "/" & DAY(A1) & "/" & YEAR(A1)
```

---

Further to the comparison

Something like this?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = Now
    Debug.Print myDate

    Dim newDate As Date
    newDate = DateAdd("d", 2, myDate)
    Debug.Print newDate

    Select Case DateDiff("d", myDate, newDate)
        Case Is > 0
            Debug.Print "newDate is newer"
        Case 0
            Debug.Print "dates are the same"
        Case Is < 0
            Debug.Print "newDate is older"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Run the macro and check out the `Immediate Window` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

`DateAdd()` adds 2 days to the newDate

`DateDiff()` returns the difference in days between the two dates

Comment: That doesn`t work for the type os date and time that I have in the problem

Comment: @user2898085 then you havent been clear in your question because this is how i interpreted it. what doesnt work? what is your input and expected output?

Comment: I have an input like this mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss in the same cell and I want extract only this mm/dd/yyyy.